# Visual Studio 22 getting crashed while publishing the MAUI Blazor Hybrid app

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, maui-blazor, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to create the MAUI Blazor Hybrid application, Visual Studio crashed (Automatically Closed) while publishing the MAUI Blazor Hybrid application to the Windows platform.

**The below steps are followed to publish**

1. Changed the build platform to the **Windows**
   [image: Changed to Windows platform]
2. Changed the build mode to the **Release**
3. Right-click on the Startup project and select the **Publish...** option
4. Visual Studio is Loading 5 to 10 sec then it's closed automatically

Why is Visual Studio 2022 closed while publishing the MAUI Blazor Hybrid application to Windows platform?
Do I need to add any configuration to the project file with the respective Windows platform publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the empty MAUI Blazor Hybrid application and checked it. There I'm able to publish the application. So I compared the `.csproj` file of both projects. In my application, the `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>` line is there, so I removed this line. Now I'm able to publish.